# Angular material style old time picker/number picker

Tags: javascript, angular, picker, numberpicker

I am looking for solution, or library that will allow me to get similar component like this: https://demo.mobiscroll.com/fullscreen/datetime/time#theme=material

What i am interested in is, not time-picker itself, but in picking number in way presented in demo (link above).

I am not even sure what should i look for, and even if i want to code it myself, i cannot find way to achieve such scroll behavior.

I appreciate any valuable info.